# Is there a French word for the Japanese オブジェ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, japonais, art

The Japanese word [オブジェ](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) means something like “avant-garde sculpture”, it does not apply to things like classical sculptures or 18th century busts. Most modern art sculptures are called オブジェ by Japanese people. I am not totally sure オブジェ is always art, as a decorative interior dead tree with no further processing can also be an オブジェ.

I can't find an equivalent word in French, is there any?

[Google Images](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7) might give you a better idea of what it is used for.
Strangely, the word actually comes from the French “objet”.

Comment: That Google search seems to include some art of persons/animated things... for example, this: http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQkVPINxqDuEkPDWjqquDZTR0PNBE7xx6Y4fJj1VfdpQeTyYORfwgSz4t0Kug

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In French (and also in English), this kind of sculptures is called **Installations**.

I give you an English link to **[Installation art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_art)** because the French one is a stub, but I think it's what you are looking for.